# PyQt4 matplotlib does not plot my real time data

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4

I am new to PyQt4 and real time plots. I am trying to plot some random real time data on PyQt4 application using matplotlib and Python2.7 . My code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import random
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
import sys
import time


class mplCanvas(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.fig = plt.figure(1)
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax.grid(True)
        self.manager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
        super(mplCanvas, self).__init__(self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.init_figure()


class CustomFigCanvas(mplCanvas):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        mplCanvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateFigure)

    def init_figure(self):

        xaxis = np.arange(0, 100, 1)
        yaxis = np.array([0]*100)
        self.ax.set_title("Realtime Waveform Plot")
        self.ax.set_xlabel("Time")
        self.ax.set_ylabel("Amplitude")
        self.ax.axis([0, 100, -1.5, 1.5])
        self.line1 = self.ax.plot(xaxis, yaxis, '-')
        self.values = []


    def addData(self):

        self.values.append(random.random() * 2 - 1)

    def updateFigure(self):

        self.addData()
        CurrentXAxis=np.arange(len(self.values)-100, len(self.values), 1)
        self.line1[0].set_data(CurrentXAxis, np.array(self.values[-100:]))
        self.ax.axis([CurrentXAxis.min(), CurrentXAxis.max(), -1.5, 1.5])
        self.manager.canvas.draw()
```

And in the main application I call `graph = CustomFigCanvas()`
But all it does is it prints the plot with a straight line at 0 and the graph does not update at all. I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong. Why my plot is not updating? I was trying several options and still have the same result. I tried to do QThread to emit samples of data but it still did not work. All I get is a straight line. Do you have any suggestions? Any tips would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Next time, please provide a [mcve] instead of writing something like *'and in the main application I call graph = CustomFigCanvas()'*. Most of the time is then spend on producing that minimal example for oneself, in order to be able to reproduce the error. This is work that should be done by the questioner, not the answerer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you had the following errors:

- You never started the timer, you should use: `{your timer}.start({period in ms})`
- Arrays have different sizes.
- Change `self.manager.canvas.draw()` to `self.draw()`
- `init_figure` was never declared in `mplCanvas`

---

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Qt4Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import random
from PyQt4 import QtCore


class mplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.fig = plt.figure(1)
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax.grid(True)
        super(mplCanvas, self).__init__(figure=self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.init_figure()

    def init_figure(self):
        pass


class CustomFigCanvas(mplCanvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        mplCanvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateFigure)
        self.timer.start(100)

    def init_figure(self):
        xaxis = np.arange(0, 100, 1)
        self.values = [0]*100
        yaxis = np.array(self.values)
        self.ax.set_title("Realtime Waveform Plot")
        self.ax.set_xlabel("Time")
        self.ax.set_ylabel("Amplitude")
        self.ax.axis([0, 100, -1.5, 1.5])
        self.line1 = self.ax.plot(xaxis, yaxis, '-')

    def addData(self):
        self.values.append(random.random() * 2 - 1)

    def updateFigure(self):
        self.addData()
        CurrentXAxis = np.arange(len(self.values)-100, len(self.values), 1)
        self.line1[0].set_data(CurrentXAxis, np.array(self.values[-100:]))
        self.ax.axis([CurrentXAxis.min(), CurrentXAxis.max(), -1.5, 1.5])
        self.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
    l = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(main_widget)
    graph = CustomFigCanvas(main_widget)
    l.addWidget(graph)
    main_widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you set up a `QTimer` but never start it. So the updating function will never be called. What you need to do is something like

```
self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateFigure)
self.timer.start(1000) # 1000 milliseconds
```

Another problem is then how you create the data to update. The way it is in the code produces arrays of different length for the x and y coordinates, leading to errors.

Here is a complete running example where I also got rid of the unnecessary double subclassing.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import random
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
import sys


class CustomFigCanvas(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax.grid(True)
        super(CustomFigCanvas, self).__init__(self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.init_figure()

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateFigure)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def init_figure(self):

        xaxis = np.arange(0, 100, 1)
        yaxis = np.array([0]*100)
        self.ax.set_title("Realtime Waveform Plot")
        self.ax.set_xlabel("Time")
        self.ax.set_ylabel("Amplitude")
        self.ax.axis([0, 100, -1.5, 1.5])
        self.line1 = self.ax.plot(xaxis, yaxis, '-')
        self.values = []
        self.fig.tight_layout()

    def addData(self):
        self.values.append(random.random() * 2 - 1)

    def updateFigure(self):
        self.addData()
        CurrentXAxis=np.arange(len(self.values))
        self.line1[0].set_data(CurrentXAxis, np.array(self.values))
        self.ax.axis([CurrentXAxis.min()-0.001, CurrentXAxis.max()+0.001, -1.5, 1.5])
        self.fig.canvas.draw()

class App(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(App, self).__init__(parent)   
        self.tab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab)
        self.tablayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.tab)
        self.canvas = CustomFigCanvas()
        self.tablayout.addWidget(self.canvas)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
thisapp = App()
thisapp.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: having the choice between several identical answers, one usually accepts the one that came first.

Comment: If you're viewing in a mobile browser you actually can't tell which came first. It just says "answered 1 hour ago" for both.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Yeah, but the other answer has bullet points and a picture, so it must be "better" ;-)